# maven plugins conflict

Tags: maven-3, wsdl2java, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I am a newbie to maven. I have two maven plugins in my maven project, when I do generate sources one of them generates sources all the time (`jaxb2-maven-plugin`) but other doesn't (`wsdl2java`) generate sources. They are conflicting with each other. I need both of them badly and they worked in the past but they don't work now. I tried commenting out `jaxb2-maven-plugin` and the other plugin `wsdl2java` works then. Is there anything that I need to do ?

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
 <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>1.3</version>
 <executions>
   <execution>
<phase>generate-sources</phase>
<goals>
        <goal>xjc</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
    <packageName>com.x.x.model</packageName>                           
<generatePackage>com.x.x.model</generatePackage>
<schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/DavisTemplates</schemaDirectory>
<outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/</outputDirectory>
</configuration>
</plugin>

    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>axistools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- SourceDirectory should only refer to the directory where the wsdl 
                    resides and not the actual wsdl file itself -->
                <sourceDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdl/</sourceDirectory>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/</outputDirectory>
                <packageSpace>com.paypal.touchstone.posapiserv</packageSpace>
                <!-- <wsdlFile>${posApiVersion}.wsdl</wsdlFile> -->
                <serverSide>false</serverSide>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```